# Java Replacing all commas with semi-colons except the ones inside quotations marks

Tags: java, replace, bluej

Replacing all commas except the ones inside quotations marks in java with CSV style user input.

I've done some research but can't wrap my head around how/where to start to do this, not sure if I can ask questions without adding any code but, if anyone could help me by suggesting functions to use/research to do this I would really appreciate it

p.s I've seen a few other posts but from what I read it wasn't working properly.

Comment: Please show sample data and code.

Comment: How about iterating over characters in text with boolean flag which will point if you are inside quotation. Add all characters to StringBuilder except if character is comma which is inside quotation. In that case add semicolon.

Comment: @OldProgrammer This isn't a question about existing code; it's not phrased the best, but it's asking about an appropriate algorithm.

Comment: That's the thing I'm not even sure where to start, but basically I need an idea on how to replace commas unless they are in quotations so if "Sam","Fred",23,"23Fredsam place, Samfred District" it would return "Sam";"Fred";23;"23Fredsam place, Samfred district"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 suggestions:

1. Use a CSV parsing library like [commons-csv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to tokenize the input and then re-join it with whichever character you want. CSV libraries are smart enough not to split on commas within quotes.
2. Implement a finite state machine (2 states: within quotes and outside quotes) to scan the input keeping track of whether or not the current character is inside quotes. When you find a comma and you're not inside quotes, replace it.

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll be looking up CSV parsing and tokenizing and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode:

```
Read character
if character is ','
   replace with ';'
else if character is '"'
   read character until it is '"'
else
   do nothing
Repeat
```

Comment: Could you go a little more into detail on how I would do this I understand the | if char is ',' replace with ';' | but how would do the  | elif character is "" read character until it is "" |

Comment: something like `else if( ch == '"' ){ while( scanner.HasNextChar() && (ch = scanner.nextChar()) != '"' ){} }`

Answer (score 0):

How about writing your own parser which would work like

```
set flag which checks if we are inside quotation to false
create buffer for changed version of original string (StringBuilder )

for (each character in string)
    if (character is comma and is inside quotation)
        add semicolon to StringBuilder
    else
        add character to StringBuilder
        if (character is quotation mark)
            reverse quotation flag

when you are done with iterating over characters get content of StringBuilder
```

Comment: I'll also look into string building, this looks to be a nice way of doing it.  Thanks